# Bootstrap 4 vs bootstrap 3 alignment

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--scripts-->
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./test.js"></script>

  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs "  onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span> -->

  <div class="row justify-content-center test" id="button1">
    <h1 class="status">Status of program</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" onclick="show(this)">Just an Idea</button>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" onclick="show(this)">In Development</button>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" onclick="show(this)">Being Polited</button>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" onclick="show(this)">Proof Tested</button>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" onclick="show(this)">Operationals</button>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div>
      <h2 class="status">Rate the value of Your Idea will Provide</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-responsive" id="table">
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Client Experience
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Collaboration
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Money
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Time
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Quality
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Hi**
I have written a small html page using bootstrap version 3.3.7 using BootstrapCDN

it just looked fine like this

[image: using Bootstrap Version 3.3.7]

After I thought to change to version 4.1.0

I just changed the CDN version from 3.3.7 to 4.1.0 from bootstrap official site but it changed whole alignment of my page like this
please help me

[image: using Bootstrap Version 4.1.0]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is a new major version, so you should expect things to break. See the migration docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#summary

Comment: when you are down voting please mention the reason because without the problem anyone won't post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because some bootstrap 3 classes are different in verison 4. You didn't provide any code so it's hard to tell which specificly are causing the problem. You can read in more details about changes here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: hi inserted code

Comment: Hi Keerthi, the problem is not with bootstrap. I changed your code a little and it works fine now https://jsfiddle.net/ojvym9ct/10/

Comment: Thank you @Mateusz but for every div should we keep justify-content-center